# How could calculate the time between dates in my dataframe to an outside date?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, datetime

Please excuse my lack of knowledge but I am completely new at this, coming from a social services background. My classmates and I are all having trouble following our prof sadly. We have a data frame that I've reduced to the 2 columns needed (an excel doc). One column has different dates. We'd like to create a new df that tells us how many months are between all those dates and `May 31, 2019`, using `DateTime`. I'd appreciate any input or reference to something similar. The most recent step I've tried is `x = DateTime.datetime(2019, 5, 31)` but I'm not sure what to do next. I also made the df into an array but I'm also not sure if I'm even supposed to do that, to begin with.

Comment: Read this so you know how you can [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

let say the column is called 'date'

first convert it to a date object:

`df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
create new column
df['days_difference'] = (df.date - x).days`

if you want it in month you can divide by 30.42?